# How can I choose a specific intersection element in a list? TypeError: unhashed type: 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, intersection

I would like to intersect two lists and print what they have in common. However, I would like to choose the specific element to intersect (e.g. `[0]` or `[hockeymatch]`, `[1]`,  etc). With x[0] or y[1], my intention is not to select the entire line of the match, but to select only [hockeymatch]. I get this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

In my code example, I would like to get this output:

```
'Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00'
```

So I would just like 'Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00', without:

- without [1.33] and [62.0], because these numbers are different from [2.5] and [125.0] despite being contained in another 'Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00'
- without 'Dallas-Arizona', 'NHL', '15:00' and 'Vancouver-Vegas', 'NHL', '20:00', because they are two different games from 'Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00'

**IMPORTANT:** This is just an example, but I will add more hockey matches. I don't want to manually print by setting only [('Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00')], but I would like to "**AUTOMATICALLY**" print any hockey match in common, even more than one match in common if there is one).

**UPDATE:** With x[0] or y[1], my intention is not to select the entire line of the match, but to select only [hockeymatch], for example ('Dallas-Arizona', 'NHL', '15:00 ')] or all of the other matches. I wanted a way to be able to select [hockeymatch], [number1], [number2] in the same line as the match.

In simple terms, I meant:

> "considering that other hockey matches will be added in the future,
> look for one or more common matches (i.e. [hockeymatch]), but exclude
> from the intersection [number1] and [number2]"

Code:

```
#x = []
#x.append([[hockeymatch], [number1], [number2]])
x = [[[('Dallas-Arizona', 'NHL', '15:00')], [1.75], [87.5]],
     [('Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00')], [2.5], [125.0]]

#y = []
#y.append([[hockeymatch], [number1], [number2]])
y = [[[('Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00')], [1.33], [62.0]],
       [('Vancouver-Vegas', 'NHL', '20:00')], [0.50], [43.0]]

test = list(set(x[0]).intersection(y[0]))
print(test)
```

P.S: For greater clarity of the code I have added the *comments* of when I create the list and how I insert the elements with append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#x = []
#x.append([[hockeymatch], [tournament], [number1], [number2]])
x = [[[('Dallas-Arizona', 'NHL', '15:00')], [1.75], [87.5]],
[('Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00')], [2.5], [125.0]]

#y = []
#y.append([[hockeymatch], [tournament], [number1], [number2]])
y = [[[('Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00')], [1.33], [62.0]],
[('Vancouver-Vegas', 'NHL', '20:00')], [0.50], [43.0]]

t1 = []
t2 = []

for i in range(len(x)):
     if i == 0:
          t1.append(tuple(x[i][0]))
     else:
          try:
               if len(x[i][0]) == 3:
                    t1.append(tuple(x[i]))
          except:
               pass

for i in range(len(y)):
     if i == 0:
          t2.append(tuple(y[i][0]))
     else:
          try:
               if len(y[i][0]) == 3:
                    t2.append(tuple(y[i]))
          except:
               pass

print(list((set(t1).intersection(set(t2)))))
```

You can simplify the code by using functions

```
x = [[[('Dallas-Arizona', 'NHL', '15:00')], [1.75], [87.5]],
[('Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00')], [2.5], [125.0]]


y = [[[('Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00')], [1.33], [62.0]],
[('Vancouver-Vegas', 'NHL', '20:00')], [0.50], [43.0]]

t1 = []
t2 = []

def matches(your_l, l_used):
     for i in range(len(l_used)):
          if i == 0:
               your_l.append(tuple(l_used[i][0]))
          else:
               try:
                    if len(l_used[i][0]) == 3:
                         your_l.append(tuple(l_used[i]))
               except:
                    pass

matches(t1, x)
matches(t2, y)

print(list((set(t1).intersection(set(t2)))))
```

Comment: I know the error occurred in this line. You pointed out the error, but you have no advice on how to fix it.
Could you show me how to fix it instead of showing me my obvious error line? Thank you

Comment: @Takao貴男  Added the fix :)

Comment: Did my answer help you ? Or you need any other fix?

Comment: Your answer is invalid for one reason: if I try to add more hockey matches in x, your code doesn't work. You wrote your code knowing that you had to manually print [('Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00')]. I would like to "automatically" print the things in common in the lists. (even more than one match in common if there is one). Can you fix your code please?

Comment: Can you provide some test cases and expected outputs? That would help.

Comment: If I try to print print(l1), I get: [('Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00'), 2.5, 125.0]. With x[0] or y[1], my intention is not to select the entire line of the match, but to select only [hockeymatch], for example ('Dallas-Arizona', 'NHL', '15:00') ] or all of the others. For example, my idea was that x[0] is [hockeymatch], x[1] is [number1], x[2] is [number2]: I wanted to apply this to all matches in the lists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250802/discussion-between-vikash-and-takao).

Comment: Try this edit..

Comment: You are great! I upvoted and accepted your answer. You have been very kind and patient. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation:

> A set is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects. The
> objects have to be hashable so that finding, adding and removing
> elements can be done faster than looking at each individual element
> every time you perform these operations.

A list is not a hashable(/immutable) data-type. That means when you try to cast x[0] into a set, you need to make sure every element in x[0] is hashable (tuples, sets, etc not lists). You could change x[0] from a list to a tuple. (rounded parenthesis instead of square brackets) to make things work.

Also, it is generally a good idea to use tuples for data that does not need to be changed, at least in place.

```
x = [((('Dallas-Arizona', 'NHL', '15:00')), 1.75, 87.5), ...
```

Edit

After making this change, say you want to find the common matches between matches stored in x and y.
You can try

```
    x = [
        (('da', 'nhl', '15:00'), 1.75, 87.5),
    (('sm', 'nhl', '18:00'), 2, 3)
]

y = [
        (('da', 'nhl', '15:00'), 1.75, 87.5),
        (('sm', 'nhl', '18:00'), 2, 3),
        (('fse', 'afww', '15:00'), 121.75, 187.5),
        (('afae', 'awfwa', '18:00'), 21, 13)

]
x_set = set(x)
y_set = set(y)
common_matches = x_set.intersection(y_set)
print([match[0] for match in common_matches])
```

This should print:

```
[('da', 'nhl', '15:00'), ('sm', 'nhl', '18:00')]
```

Comment: you didn't understand my question. I don't want to print the numbers 1.75, 87.5 as well, just 'Dallas-Arizona', 'NHL', '15:00'.

Comment: I'm still looking for answers. Any new solution is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Mutable `list`s are causing you grief.

Let's use some immutable `tuple`s!

```
from collections import namedtuple
from operator import itemgetter

Game = namedtuple("Game", "match, league, time, num1, num2")

x = [
    Game("Dallas-Arizona", "NHL", "15:00", 1.75, 87.5),
    Game("Seattle-Minnesota", "NHL", "18:00", 2.5, 125.0),
]
y = [
    Game("Seattle-Minnesota", "NHL", "18:00", 1.33, 62.0),
    Game("Vancouver-Vegas", "NHL", "20:00", 0.50, 43.0),
]


def getter(n: int, games: list[Game]):
    return list(map(itemgetter(n), games))


print(getter(0, x))
print(getter(0, y))

print("\nintersection:")
print(set(getter(0, x)) & set(getter(0, y)))
print("\nunion:")
print(set(getter(0, x)) | set(getter(0, y)))
```

output:

```
['Dallas-Arizona', 'Seattle-Minnesota']
['Seattle-Minnesota', 'Vancouver-Vegas']

intersection:
{'Seattle-Minnesota'}

union:
{'Seattle-Minnesota', 'Dallas-Arizona', 'Vancouver-Vegas'}
```

When displaying a `set`,
the output will usually be a bit easier to read
if you view the `sorted( ... )`
version of it.

---

Your question didn't give names to the business
concepts, like what the 1st three fields denote
or what the two numbers are all about.

If you like, you could define a 3-tuple
and then define a bigger named tuple
which includes it. Please feel free
to [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
such source code if you test it and find
it addresses your use case.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
list(set(x[1]).intersection(y[0][0]))
#[('Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00')]
```

Since x and y are nested lists. So, you were getting error when you were applying `set()` directly on 2D list.

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Yes, it works. A curiosity: if I want to access only [number1] or [number2], how can I do it? (without ('Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00'). Thank you

Comment: you can do `x[1][0]` to get `Seattle-Minnesota`

Comment: Your answer is invalid for one reason: if I try to add more hockey matches in x, your code doesn't work. You wrote your code knowing that you had to manually print [('Seattle-Minnesota', 'NHL', '18:00')]. I would like to "automatically" print the things in common in the lists. (even more than one match in common if there is one). Can you fix your code please?

Comment: If I add matches in x and run the code, I get an error, because Seattle-Minnesota is not found because the position in the list will be different. When I add more matches, I won't know where Seattle-Minnesota is at x. With your code, you specify where Seattle-Minnesota is, but I would like it to be searched automatically. can you help me? Thank you

Comment: I would say that once you have both the complete lists with you `x` and `y` you can unnest them and see what is your actual requirement. Once you get the correct idea of indices of all the values you can intersect them with set according to your needs.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. I updated my question by adding IMPORTANT and UPDATE to it. Can you re-read please? I don't want to manually set a particular match like you did, but want it to be automatically pulled (even more than one match). Can you fix your code please? It's my fault that I didn't explain myself well. Thank you